# Java Virtual Machine Sources to Learn

Tags: java, jvm

What are some good sources to learn about Java Virtual Machine for newbies?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Comment: You need to include some detail, what is it you want to learn? Is it the inner workings of the JVM or is it Java programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following books are good to learn about JVM.

[Inside Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071350934)

[Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528)

-Siva

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Virtual Machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) is the definitive source.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the source for classes you use. They are in teh src.zip of the JDK, but most IDEs willf ind it for you.  When you are using a class, use `<ctrl>+<click>` the method or class to see its source.